# How to click on link in drop down box?

Tags: imacros

Is it possible for iMacros to hover over a link which then produces a drop down box which I then need iMacros to click on one of the options in the drop down box?

Thanks in advance for any help,
quizzit

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to work around this limitation would be to take the URL of the page you're trying to reach, paste it in a URL GOTO statement, like so:

```
URL GOTO=www.example.com
```

This method with eliminate the hover & click steps, increasing script efficiency.  However, if you're trying to test web element's dropdown functionality, this isn't for you.

Best,
code1